# CLLocationManager() Location is nil in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios-simulator, cllocationmanager

I'm try to get `latitude` and `longitude` but location is always `nil`.

```
class FinalizeOrderController: UIViewController {

    var locManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        currentLocation = CLLocation()
        locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func FinaliseOrder(_ sender: Any) {
        if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse ||
            CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways) {
            currentLocation = locManager.location
            print(locManager.location?.coordinate.latitude) //prints nil
            print(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude) //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
        }


        lbl1.text = "\(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
        lbl2.text = "\(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)"
    }
```

I add **info.plist** keys and run simulator location from `Xcode` and chooses simulator location from debug but no way always `nil`

Comment: Check Simulator - Debug - Location is not NULL

Comment: i chooses Apple

Comment: You can't just access the `location` property. You need to wait for the callback to the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method.

Comment: i don't need the location update   ,      
now it run good and prints apple location 
i note that it take time to change location when i chooses a custom location 
apple location stills the simulator location

Comment: make sure Debug -> Location is not set to None in Simulator

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
var currentLocation:CLLocation?
```

**Conform Delegate**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

**In ViewDidLoad**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager = CLLocationManager();
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

        if (authorizationStatus == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined) {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        } else {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
```

**In Delegate**

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
     currentLocation = locations[locations.count-1] as CLLocation

    print("locations = \(currentLocation)")
   // lbl1.text = "\(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)";
   // lbl2.text = "\(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)";
}
```

**In button action**

```
@IBAction func FinaliseOrder(_ sender: Any) {

        lbl1.text = "\(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
        lbl2.text = "\(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)"
}
```